# Extracting Network properties from a shortest path analysis QGIS

Tags: gis, shortest-path, qgis

Im using QGIS with a layer containing different routes to calculate the shortest path from point A to point B.  This algorithm returns the shortest path graphically (new layer) overlapped to the original route, the cost (time) and point A and B coordinates.  I want to know if there is a way to extract the data from the initial layer of the routes that the algorithms selected.  For example if the original layer routes have data of state, road length in miles, etc.  I want to extract this data with the shortest path.